# How to override logging configuration when using shared config with Entlib5?

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using Enterprise Library 5 logging block in a scenario where there is a common (shared) configuration for all applications and I'd like to override some of the shared setting in a specific application.

I followed instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664552%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#AdvancedConfigSharingConfig) (Applying Common Configuration Structure for Application) and was able to use shared logging setting in my app.

The question is how can I override shared setting i.e. change Rolling Flat File Trace Listener fileName property? Do you have any working examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Configuration Sources Lab from the set of Hands-On Labs available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=6932).